# Simulating a current transformer in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, current-transformer

I am trying to simulate a circuit which I purchased. It is a 5 A/5 mA CT conditioning  circuit which I have attached.
[image]

1. I am unable to simulate the circuit, because the CT is not ground-referenced. If I create a voltage source (500 mV<sub>RMS</sub> sine) it will be incorrect, because the voltage source will get ground-referenced, which is not the actual case. Can any workaround be suggested?
2. Is the circuit I have drawn logical? I am unable to understand the working of U1 because the loop is closed through a capacitor.

*The circuit has been updated to correct previous errors.Please read the comments below for more clarity.*

Comment: The circuit is wrong; if you purchased it you should ask for the circuit diagram and post it into your question rather than show your LTSpice interpretation.

Comment: Nothing forces you to ground a voltage source in LTspice. You can't leave it entirely floating, but that's not the case here. Anyway, there's at least something missing from your circuit (maybe a 10K resistor across C2), and C5 probably should not be there.

Comment: I'm guessing that each opamp has a capacitor and 100k resistor in the feedback loop (C2-R5, C5-R9). 183pF sounds like a weird value, I'm inclined to think they're marked 183 and are 0.018uF.

Comment: This is one of those cheap chinese arduino add on boards. The resellers definitely dont have a circuit diagram ! Ok I will check it in more detail and correct the schematic

Comment: 183pF is what I measured with a LCR meter. There are no markings on the cap.

Comment: Note that a "CT" is a "current transformer" ... So you need a "primary" which in general is a "one turn". And you pass through the CT with one wire ...

Comment: @Antonio51  Thank you.  I was gonna ask what the hell a "CT" is.

Comment: @Antonio51 That's what I was going to ask: where is the trafo? I don't see one.

Comment: I have updated the schematic , just in case someone happens upon this thread. As hinted by @SpehroPefhany and GodJihyo , I have replace the current transformer with a voltage source across the burden resistor and re verified the schematics at the  OpAmp. Now the simulation works.

Comment: @MumbaiVerve I'm afraid I still have bad news: that "burden resistor" does nothing because it's across a voltage source which, in SPICE, has zero internal resistance (unless otherwise specified). So, your simulation may work, but I'd be careful with their interpretation. Also, your title is different than the body: you're asking about simulating a *current transformer*, but the body says "a CT *conditioning circuit*". Not the same.

Answer (score 3):

From [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/current-transformer.html),

[image]

Here is the "equivalent" schematic of a CT transformer for use with Arduino (5V).

[image]